# How can i use Tensorflows official models from the TF Model Garden?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-model-garden, yolov7

Through the [TensorFlow Model Garden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official) TensorFlow provides official models. However it isn't really clear, how you can use the models.

Let's say I would want to use TensorFlows Version of [YOLOv7](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/projects/yolo), how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the TensorFlow Model Garden repository from GitHub, navigate to the `object_detection` directory in the cloned repository and download the pre-trained YOLOv7 model checkpoint. Use the downloaded checkpoint to run inference on your images or videos.
You can find detailed instructions and code examples in the[TensorFlow Model Garden documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy)